# Sqlalchemy model form error when using sqlalchemy.types.Time

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I am getting error when i use sqlalchemy.types.Time as follows in my flask application:

```
class Shift(db.Model):
    start_time = db.Column(db.Time)
    end_time = db.Column(db.Time)
```

Then in my views -- using model_form:

```
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.orm import model_form
from flask.ext.wtf import Form

ShiftForm = model_form(Shift, Form, db_session=db.session)
```

This raises an error:

> wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.orm.ModelConversionError: Could not find field converter for start_time ()

Could you guys help me with where I am going wrong?

PS - I am using SQLAlchemy==1.0.13.